# Lagging within a dataset

Tags: r, lag

I tried to creat lagged columns for specific columns within a timeseries dataset but it seems that it returns incorrect values for one of them (lag_PS , ccode:200, 280, 278 are NA while the original values are 1)

```
library("dplyr")
## add lagged column to PS & CL
data_dplyr <- data %>%
group_by(ccode) %>%
dplyr::mutate(lag_PS = dplyr::lag(PS, n = 1, default = NA)) %>%
dplyr::mutate(lag_CL = dplyr::lag(CL, n = 1, default = NA)) %>%
as.data.frame()

ccode   Country year    CL  PS  lag_PS  lag_CL
158    Taiwan   2012    2   1   NA       NA
158    Taiwan   2011    2   1   1        2
158    Taiwan   2010    2   1   1        2
158    Taiwan   2009    2   1   1        2
158    Taiwan   2008    1   1   1        2
158    Taiwan   2007    1   1   1        1
158    Taiwan   2006    1   1   1        1
158    Taiwan   2004    1   1   1        1
158    Taiwan   2002    NA  1   1        1
158    Taiwan   2000    NA  1   1        NA
158    Taiwan   1999    NA  1   1        NA
158    Taiwan   1996    NA  1   1        NA
158    Taiwan   1992    NA  1   1        NA
200    Czech    1990    NA  1   NA       NA
280    Germany  1989    NA  1   NA       NA
278    Germany  1990    NA  1   NA       NA
158    Taiwan   2015    2   1   1        NA
158    Taiwan   2014    2   2.5 1        2
158    Taiwan   2003    2   2.5 2.5      2
158    Taiwan   1998    NA  2.5 2.5      2
158    Taiwan   1997    NA  2.5 2.5      NA
158    Taiwan   1995    NA  2.5 2.5      NA
158    Taiwan   1994    NA  2.5 2.5      NA
```

How could I get rid of this issue?

Comment: You have grouped by `ccode`, and each of the three rows you refer to are the only members of their own group. They are single row groups, so there is nothing to lag. You have specified NA as the default value. If you want the whole column lagged without respect to ccode, you'll need to ungroup first, though it seems unlikely this is what you want.

Comment: And quick tip: You can combine multiple statements in one `mutate` separated by a comma.

Comment: thanks you both Allan & Oliver, those hints were great!